# Android Studio Recyclerview (horizontal) - remove animation when leaving view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I have created a simple recycler view within a linear layout. When I scroll to the right I want the items 
to disappear behind my frameLayout. (It should look like you cant see the items anymore because they are behind the frameLayout).

Unfortunately, the items appear do move behind a invisible wall (the left border of the recycler view) instead of behind my frameLayout. Is there a way to remove the animation for items leaving the recyclerview?

Thanks for any help!

Code:

```
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_exerciseCards"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/view_newexercise_deck"
            android:elevation="4dp" />

        <com.example.projecttraining0.VerticalTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:rotation="180"

            android:text="My Exercises"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZ52P.png)

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have added a screenshot. My problem is the line, behind which the card disappears. I think you can see that the best at the bottom blue part.

Answer (score 0):

By using LinearLayout your FrameLayout and RecyclerView get placed one next to each other with no overlap. If you want your RecyclerView to be the full width you can use a ConstraintLayout instead of your parent LinearLayout.

You can constrain your RecyclerView to the parent so it fills the entire screen. And also put the RecyclerView first in the hierarchy and the FrameLayout second, so that the FrameLayout will be on top and occlude the RecyclerView.

You can learn a lot about ConstraintLayout [here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout). There are also a lot of video tutorials on YouTube.

Comment: Thank you for your effort! I have tried your recommendations but I still end up with the same problem. I have to set a padding to the recyclerview so it is not overlapping with my FrameLayout in the beginning. If I do so the recyclerview does move behind the FrameLayout but there is still this line you can see in the screenshot. And that is what I try to get rid off. I will update my code in case I have not understood you correctly.